# Scroll to the very bottom of UIScrollView when Keyboard appears (AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

I am trying to scroll to the bottom content of the UIScrollView when the keyboard is shown, but the method setContentOffset doesnt seem to work. I am using AutoLayout on Interface Builder. Perhaps this is what causes the problem? Any thoughts?

How could I scroll to the bottom of my UIScrollView when my the keyboard is shown.

P.S.: It will show the textField just fine, *what I need is to show the very bottom of the UIScrollView when the keyboard is shown*

Thank You!!

Below is my current code

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    var bottomOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: mainScrollView.contentSize.height - mainScrollView.bounds.size.height);
    mainScrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true);
}

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var userInfoDictionary: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!;

    var keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfoDictionary.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size;

    var contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0);

    mainScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    mainScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    var contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    mainScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    mainScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add something similar to this in your `keyboardDidShow` method:

```
var offset = scrollView.contentOffset
offset.y = scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom - scrollView.bounds.size.height
scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this working in iOS 11, Swift 4. Not sure if something changed since this answer. Even if I manually set a value to `offset.y` it changes nothing. Still just scrolls to show the textfield and not scroll to bottom.

Comment: The animation to show the textfield is still going when you try to scroll. Do DispatchQueue.main.async

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem as the original poster and couldn't get the other answer to work. I think it has something to do with iOS 11's feature of automatically scrolling the textfield into view though this is unconfirmed.

I did find a couple other ways to handle this though.

### Swift 4, iOS 11

#### 1. Using UIView.animate

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}, completion: { (done) in
    var offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset
    offset.y = keyboardSize.height
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
})
```

#### 2. Using the Safe Area (New in iOS 11)

(Note: This may not be as good if there are existing insets from things like a tab bar or tool bar at the bottom)

```
additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom = keyboardSize.height
var offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset
offset.y = keyboardSize.height
self.scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
```

#### 3. Executing on the Main Thread

```
scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    var offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset
    offset.y = keyboardSize.height
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To me scrolling to the bottom of a scroll view means setting an **offset** equal to the **total content height** minus the actual **scroll view height**.

For instance, to scroll to the bottom of a UIScrollView when the keyboard appears I use the following code:

Objective-C

```
- (void)onKeyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSValue *value = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = value.CGRectValue.size.height;
    self.scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight;
    CGPoint offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.size.height - keyboardHeight;
    offset.y = self.scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollViewHeight;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}
```

Swift 3

```
func onKeyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let value = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] {
        let keyboardHeight = (value as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size.height
        self.scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
        var offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset
        let scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.size.height - keyboardHeight
        offset.y = self.scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollViewHeight
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The bottom constraint is changed to the keyboard height when it appears and back to 0 when it disappears.

Interestingly the scroll view actual height is not just `self.scrollView.frame.size.height` (at least when the keyboard just appeared). I had to subtract the keyboard size to obtain the real value.